# Prevent source to load twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, highcharts

It would be nice if someone can shed a new idea on the below situation and sorry if it has been asked before. I could not find similar situation.

I have a dynamically generated page which I don't have control of. I need to add multiple iframes in it and load highcharts. Code for test.html:

```
<html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <script>
 ....
```

code for all.html:

```
 <html>
<iframe id="one" src="test.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="two" src="test.html"></iframe>
</html>
```

Questions:

1- In general, if a 
`<script src="some.js" />` 
is added to the html but never used in the page, will it download on the user web-browser?

2- If I add `<script src="some.js" />` in different iframes on the same main page, will it download for each of the iframes or it would detect that it has already been loaded?

3- how can I solve the issue of not putting the `<script src>` on the main page but preventing the download on all iframes and download for the first only? iframes are constructed dynamically and it will be difficult to put a flag to check if it has already been loaded for any of the iframes.

> > > > I need to prevent loading on user side twice... meaning not to download the file on user browser twice. However, using above iframes, i want it to execute twice .. yes.

Many thanks!

Comment: if I've understood your question correctly, you get all this behaviour for free assuming the browser has caching switched on. The scripts will need to be *executed* separately in each iframe, but they should only be downloaded once. Use the network tab in a browser debugger to observe this.

Comment: yeah but I saw this article and it sounds it is not doing it.http://blog.develop.com/blogs/bid/232857/Preventing-JavaScript-Files-from-Loading-Multiple-Times

Comment: Also, if it does not load twice, how the charts would be added onLoad? I tested the above example and charts appear onLoad for both iframes.. Kind of puzzled.

Comment: you need to understand the difference between loading and executing, do you want to avoid executing twice?

Comment: Sorry for my modest knowledge. I need to prevent loading on user side twice... meaning not to download the file on user browser twice. However, using above iframes, i want it to execute twice .. yes.

Comment: the article you linked to was avoiding executing twice. You get caching for free from the browser, no extra work on your part is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions in order...

1. There is no such thing as a script tag being "used" on the page, if the script tag is present in the html, that file will be downloaded (or retrieved from the cache) and executed.
2. If you have multiple script tags pointing to the same URL, the file will be downloaded only once (and then cached), but it will be executed multiple times (once for each script tag).
3. It's still not clear if you understand the difference between loading and executing a script. If you only want to avoid loading repeatedly, relax, the browser has that covered. If you want to avoid executing repeatedly, you're going to need to write code for that logic, set a flag in your script and only run if it hasn't been set yet. So, some.js might have :

   if(!window.scriptHasRun) {
     window.scriptHasRun = true;
     // do something useful here, just once.
   }

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is more related to the fact that Highcharts throws an error if it is executed a second time.

His top level page includes the highcharts library, therefore, when the iFrame navigates to a new page which also includes the library, an error is thrown and the charts fail...

Answer (score 0):

1- Whatever is on the html page will load at least once, unless you prevent it with some code.

2- Caching only works automatically for images, the rest will probably will load again if it's ajax or whatever, also it depends on the script of course.

3- you can use local cache feature of html5, pretty easy to implement, if you are working with json objects, just line them up and iterate on wherever you want.

Comment: caching works for images... and files loaded using script tags, like in the question...

Comment: I am not using html5. Simply, the situation is that, I need the script to download on user browser only if at least one of the iframes is used and only once to download but of course load charts using the iframes above... Just checking if this is possible somehow. thanks again

Comment: what does your data look like?  no idea?

Comment: you can even manifest appcache option in the html pages you want to be cached and try that, but is your html being appended on the fly?

Comment: you can insert your results into a html and apply that to every iframe, meaning you can do everything in one script.

Comment: if you are talking about triggering scripts in the iframe htmls, yeah if they have the same names, most likely they will only load once.  but as some folk said above, that has nothing to do with execution